# Co-ordinating batch processing in Akka

Tags: akka, batch-processing

I need to batch process 2 large files one after the other in Akka and I'm trying to figure out the best way to co-ordinate that in a controlling actor. The lines in each file can be processed in parallel but all of the lines from the first file must be processed before any of the lines from the second file can be processed.

I was thinking of having the following actors:

- File1WorkerActor - Processes a single line from the first file.
- File2WorkerActor - Processes a single line from the second file.
- File1Actor - Delegates the lines from the first file to multiple worker actors.
- File2Actor - Delegates the lines from the second file to multiple worker actors.
- TopLevelActor - Asks File1Actor to process file 1, waits for it to complete then asks File2Actor to process file 2.

The thing I'm not sure about is, how do the file actors know when all the workers have finished and how does the TopLevelActor know when File1Actor is finished?

I was thinking that the FileActor would just hold a counter for the number of lines in a given file and the workers would send a message back for each processed line. After the counter counts down it would send a message back to TopLevelActor. Is there any problem with this approach? Or would it be better to implement some kind of Future handling?

Comment: sounds like you want to implement an async fork-join: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93join_queue

Comment: I ended up implementing this using the work pulling pattern described in this blog post from Derek Wyatt: http://letitcrash.com/post/29044669086/balancing-workload-across-nodes-with-akka-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution sounds correct to me. Also you me be interesting to check FSM and/or become/unbecome functionality to avoid another task submission to workers when previous task are not completed